# Calling A Method Inside An If Statememt

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

I am trying to create a simple hangman game where there is a single player and multiplayer option. I am trying to  say that after running the intro method, if the response is 1 then the single player class will invoke and if the response is 2 the multiplayer class will invoke. I assume that the most efficient way is to put both the options into if statements, except for if you run it how it is right now, and press 2 for multiplayer, it will ask the question in the intro method again, so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the if-statements. I've tried using brackets, and if I remove the second if-statement and just put else for multiplayer, I can press any number that isn't 1 and it will say "multiplayer" and I only want 2 to take me to the multiplayer class. All my classes say right now are a void method that says "This is coming from single player mode" and so on. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong with the logic portion, so if someone could please help!

```
package hangman;
import java.util.*;

public class HangmanMain
{
    public static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static int intro(int num)
    {
        int answer = num;
        System.out.println("How many players are playing? Press 1 for single player and 2 for multiplayer:");
        int response = input.nextInt();
        if (response == 1)
            answer = 1;
        if (response == 2)
            answer = 2;
        return answer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SinglePlayer single = new SinglePlayer();
        Multiplayer multi = new Multiplayer();
        if (intro(0) == 1)
            single.test1(0);
        if (intro(0) == 2)
            multi.test2(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `intro(0)` twice. Store the result in a variable, and compare that in your `if`(s). Use `else` and also please use braces like

```
int introVal = intro(1);
if (introVal == 1) {
    single.test1(0);
    // .. more stuff here.
} else if (introVal == 2) {
    multi.test2(0);
    // or here.
}
```

Also, your `intro()` method could use

```
public static int intro(int num)
{
    System.out.println("How many players are playing? Press 1 for single "
        + "player and 2 for multiplayer:");
    int response = input.nextInt();
    if (response == 1 || response == 2) {
        return response;
    }
    return num;
}
```